# What does +x mean in Bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

What does +x mean in the below statement?

```
if[ -z ${FSV_ROOT+x} ]
```

Comment: Please [read the `bash` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

Answer (score 4):

Read up on *Use Alternative Value*. See *[2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)*.

In parameter expansion, if a parameter is unset or null, null shall be substituted; otherwise, the expansion of word shall be substituted. Use of the colon in the format shall result in a test for a parameter that is unset or null; omission of the colon shall result in a test for a parameter that is only unset.

So in your case:

If FSV_ROOT is set and not null, substitute x

If FSV_ROOT set but null, substitute x

If FSV_ROOT is unset, substitute null

Comment: Does "null" mean empty string, i.e. "" ?

Answer (score 1):

`${parameter+alt_value}`: if parameter is set (to any value including null), return "alt_value" instead.

`[ -z ${parameter+x} ]` will return true if parameter has not been set at all. The "x" has no special meaning and could be replaced with any non-null string. It is there primarily because just `[ -z $parameter ]` would also return true if parameter were set to null - but it also helps to avoid a syntax error if $parameter were set to expand to more than one word, which would require quoting of the variable otherwise.

See also:
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMALTV
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html

Do not confuse with the common use of +x with the `chmod` command, where it means to set the execute bit on a file.